# detect a person even he changes his ip address

Tags: php, http, networking, ip

I'm new at Laravel and PHP. i want to block the users **who have failed to login** more than 3 times in 5 minutes for a certain period of time, say 30 minutes.

i have done this process completely and it works but the problem is the person can change his IP address using VPN so easily and start to send request again and also if i detect the person by browser, he can change his browser.

so i have to work with which information that the person can not change it easily?

i try using `user_agent` and also `IP` but they are not constant. and also i try to set a cookie in browser but it isn't good idea.

i expect find a field in the client information that person can't change it so easy, so i can detect the person correctly.
thanks for your help ^_^

Comment: You should never use IP address - IPs change, people in offices often share an IP, people using a terminal server share an IP.

Comment: You could add a field to your user table to set a status locked with the time when the user was locked. Next time check if the user is locked and/or if enough time has already passed. Additionally, make a failed Login field with a timestamp to count.

Comment: @Uwe on login you don't necessarily know who the user is.

Comment: There is no good way to do this, without there being a way to work around it. In cases like this you can combine 2 or 3 imperfect methods, like, for example, cookies, ip address and requiring javascript, to get something that works 99.9% of the time.

Comment: `i want to block the users who have failed to login`...if they try to use the same username repeatedly, you can use that to track it. You could possibly use that in conjunction with IP address, to see if attempts are being made on the same user account from different IPs. Of course if they're trying different usernames in order to probe the system then that's more difficult. But blocking their IP after a few attempts will still make it awkward for them to do lots of attempts.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I assumed that the Laravel Application would need the credentials for a failed login, by which the user could be identified. Otherwise, how could a login fail?

Comment: @Uwe Suppose I am user "kikosoft", but I enter "kikisoft", how then would you know the user?

Comment: @ADyson: The danger of your method is that I could block your account by using your username repeatedly. Oh, we happen to use the same IP address and not like each other very much....

Comment: @KIKOSoftware true enough. Probably these are just factors of several which might be taken into account. MFA should also be considered, to increase security (although it may not solve the problem you've just alluded to).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - As a user, I would rather have a service block my account for a bit (and notify me) if someone tries to brute force it, than they attempting some imperfect IP blocking or similar that could be bypassed.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, anything in need of protection should use MFA.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I would have ignored this case from a Backend perspective as for me user = user account and not a person. But you are right, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: you need to 1st establish levels of security and/or emails that you want to implement

Long answer with some suggestions:

1. have a user login with an OTP (one time password) sent to them via email/ whatsapp/ SMS, etc.
2. Alternatively, use a double authentication method to login people
3. Use 3rd party login services like logging in via Google/ FB, etc. (not recommended)

Use any of the above with a sound session handling system, and use https (& if you don't want to rely on cookies : debatable topic if you use https), then embed session in your requests (GET/ Post, etc)

Hope this helps

Comment: i already use this method thanks. but in this case these methods can not help us. cause there is maybe no valid username.

Answer (score -3):

You could try to store the information in the clients browser with https://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: And any knowledgeable user  who  doesn't like that will just delete the cookie, or switch profiles, or switch browsers, or switch devices. So that's not going to be very effective. A solution reliant on client-side tech is  likely to be trivial to bypass.

Comment: They might not even make the requests through a browser. Never rely on the client for security. And the link points to a library that's 12 years old and uses many out-dated technologies (Java (I guess Java applet?), Flash, Silverlight etc)

Comment: Your answer used outdated technology.